# Confused with object arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

So I first learned Java and now I'm trying to switch over to C++. I'm having a little difficulty getting arrays to work correctly.

Right now I am simply trying to create an array of object "Player" and populate it with one. But I get an error.

```
Player* players = new Player[1];
players[0] = new Player(playerWidth, playerHeight, 20, 1);
```

The error says: 
the operand "=" matches these operands. Operand types are: Player = Player *

I can't understand why this doesn't work?

Comment: First lesson: stop using `new` unless you really really need to.

Comment: You don't need `new` to create an object in C++ and you should prefer `std::array` and `std::vector` instead of built-in arrays.

Comment: The advice about new is sound.  Remember, C++ isn't garbage collected, which means when you use new, you're stuck manually freeing the memory.

Comment: @sgar91: In Java it does not return an object, it creates an object and returns a reference. In C++ it creates an object and it returns a pointer. The main difference is that for all but primitive types in Java (language with reference semantics) everything is a reference, while in C++ (language with value semantics) everything is an object (including pointers)

Comment: @sgar91 C++ semantics are indeed very different from Java. `new` however is rather similar (though related concepts differ): In Java, it returns a reference (in the Java sense), while in C++ it returns a raw pointer. And a Java reference is very much like a more restricted C++ pointer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

What the error is saying is that you are trying to assign a value of the wrong type to the variable. When the error says `Player = Player *` that means that the variable on the left hand side is a `Player` and the value on the right hand side is a `Player *`.

```
players[0] = new Player(playerWidth, playerHeight, 20, 1);
```

The problem is similar to if you were to do:

```
int x;
x = "Hello, World!";
```

The left and right hand types don't match, and there's no natural conversion, so you get an error.

---

The first problem is that you're coming from a Java background, and Java uses pointers a lot but hides them from you. C++ doesn't hide them at all. The consequence is that C++ has different syntax for explicitly dealing with pointers. Java got rid of all that and mostly used the regular, non-pointer syntax from C++ for dealing with pointers.

```
Java:                                  C++:

Player player = new Player();          Player *player = new Player();

Player player2;                        Player *player2 = nullptr;

** no equivalent in java **            Player player3;

player.foo();                          player->foo();

** no equivalent in java **            player3.foo();

** no equivalent in java **            *player;

** no equivalent in java **            &player2;
```

It's very important to understand the difference between working with pointers and working directly with an object:

```
Java:                                  C++:

Player a = new Player();               Player *a = new Player();
Player b = a;                          Player *b = a;
b.foo();                               b->foo();
```

In this code there's only a single object, and you can access it through either `a` or `b` and it doesn't make a difference, `a` and `b` are both pointers to the same object.

```
C++:

Player c = Player();
Player d = c;
d.foo();
```

In this code there are two objects. They are distinct, and doing something to `d` does not affect `c`.

If in Java you learned about the distinction between 'primitive' types like `int` and Object types like `String` then one way to think about it is that in C++ all objects are primitive. If we look back at your code and use this 'C++ objects are like Java primitives' rule you can maybe see better what's wrong:

```
Java:
int[] players = new int[1];
players[0] = new int(playerWidth); // huh???
```

That should make it clear that the right hand side of the assignment should simply be a Player value rather than a dynamic allocation of a new player object. For an int in java this looks like `players[0] = 100;`. Since Object types in Java are different Java doesn't have a way to write Object *values* the way you can write `int` values. But C++ does; `players[0] = Player(playerWidth, playerHeight, 20, 1);`

---

The second problem is that arrays in C are weird and C++ inherited that.

Pointers in C and C++ allow 'pointer arithmetic. If you have a pointer to an object you can add to or subtract from it and get a pointer to a different object. Java has nothing similar to this.

```
int x[2]; // create an array of two ints, the ints are 'adjacent' to one another
// if you take the address for the first one and 'increment' it
// then you'll have a pointer to the second one.

int *i = &x[0]; // i is a pointer to the first element
int *j = &x[1]; // j is a pointer to the second element

// i + 1 equals j
// i equals j - 1
```

Additionally the array index operator `[]` works on pointers. `x[5]` is equivalent to `*(x+5)`. This means that pointers can be used as arrays, and that is idiomatic and expected in C and C++. In fact it's even baked into C++.

In C++ when you use `new` to dynamically allocate an object, e.g. `new Player`, you normally get a pointer to the type you specified. In this example you get `Player *`. But when you dynamically allocate an array, e.g. `new Player[5]`, it's different. Instead of getting back a pointer to an array of five `Players`, you actually get back a pointer to the first element. This is just like any other `Player *`:

```
Player *p   = new Player;    // not an array
Player *arr = new Player[5]; // an array
```

The only thing that makes this pointer different is that when you do pointer arithmetic on it you get pointers to valid `Player` objects:

```
Player *x = p + 1;   // not pointing at a valid Player
Player *y = arr + 3; // pointing at the fourth array element
```

---

`new` and `delete` are hard to use correctly if you use them without protection. To demonstrate this:

```
int *x = new int;
foo();
delete x;
```

This code is error prone and probably wrong. Specifically, if `foo()` throws an exception then `x` is leaked.

In C++ whenever you acquire a responsibility, such as when you call `new` you acquire the responsibility to call `delete` at a later time, you should remember

> **R.A.I.I.**
>      Responsibility* Acquisition Is Initialization

<sub>* More frequently people say 'resource acquisition is initialization', but resources are only one kind of responsibility. I was persuaded to use the latter term by Jon Kalb in one of his [Exception Safe C++](http://exceptionsafecode.com/) talks.</sub>

R.A.I.I. means that whenever you acquire a responsibility, it should look like you're initializing an object; specifically you're initializing a special object who's purpose is to manage that responsibility for you. One example of such an type is `std::unique_ptr<int>` which will manage pointers to `int`s allocated with `new`:

```
C++:

std::unique_ptr<int> x(new int);
foo();
// no 'delete x;'
```

To manage your `Player` array you'd use `std::unqiue_ptr` like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Player[]> players(new Player[1]);
players[0] = Player(playerWidth, playerHeight, 20, 1);
```

Now the `unique_ptr` will handle that allocation for you and you don't need to call `delete` yourself. (N.B. when you allocate an array you should give `unique_ptr` an array type; `std::unique_ptr<Player[]>`, and when you allocate anything else you use a non-array type, `std::unique_ptr<Player>`.)

Of course C++ has an even more specialized R.A.I.I. type for managing arrays, `std::vector`, and you should prefer that to using `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::vector<Player> players(1);
players[0] = Player(playerWidth, playerHeight, 20, 1);
```

Or in C++11:

```
std::vector<Player> players { Player(playerWidth, playerHeight, 20, 1) };
```

Comment: Wow this is some really great stuff. Really appreciate the comparisons between java and c++, it was hard to get my mind around the pointer concepts but you did an exceptional job illustrating it. Thank you

Comment: Well illustrated. I wouldn't call arrays in C/C++ wierd, though; they are logical and tied to a simple pointer arithmetic. Have to admit, though, pointers are tricky, and syntax like "5[array]" (yes, that is valid C/C++ syntax) only goes to show how tricky they can be!

Comment: @Helixirr The weird things about arrays aren't so much anything to do with pointers, but all the inconsistencies and special cases; for example you can't return an array by value, if you try to declare an array value parameter then the language 'adjusts' it for you to something else, array objects aren't assignable, and many more.

Answer (score 8):

Your types don't match. And it's no wonder, you're trying to store a `Player*` into an already-allocated `Player`!

```
Player* players = new Player[1];
```

This creates an array of length 1, containing an instantiated `Player`, and stores the whole thing into a `Player*`. The type of `players[0]` is going to be `Player`.

```
players[0] = new Player(...)
```

This attempts to create a new `Player*` and store it in the array. But the array contains `Player` objects. You should just say

```
players[0] = Player(...)
```

---

Alternatively, and I'm going to guess this is more appropriate for you, you should stop using `new` entirely, and use a `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<Player> players;
players.push_back(Player(playerWidth, playerHeight, 20, 1));
// or players.emplace_back(playerWidth, playerHeight, 20, 1);
```

Not only is this much easier to use, but you also don't have to remember to `delete` it later. When the `std::vector` goes out of scope, it will automatically destruct. Also, unlike your array, `std::vector` can contain any number of objects, so you can add new players or delete existing players at will.

There are other data structures as well that may possibly be more suited for you, depending on your exact use, but `std::vector` is a good starting point.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is, type of your variable

```
players[0]
```

is Player (object). However, operator "new" (new Player) returns a pointer (Player*)

If you want to have only one object, correct way to do it will be:

```
Player* player = new Player(playerWidth, playerHeight, 20, 1);
```

And don't forget in C++ you need to clean the mess after yourself - somewhere in the end call

```
delete player;
```

for every object you've created. C++ does not have Garbage Collector - meaning all manually created (by "new") objects stay until you manually delete them.

Comment: no mention of vector?  Or array?  value semantics?  `unique_ptr`?

Comment: I can throw whole boost/C++0x documentation into him, but this is not the stuff that helps to grasp basic concepts.

Comment: value semantics are a key part of C++.  This answer merely shows how to make Java-like code compile in a C++ compiler, with no indication that there are far better and simpler ways.  I'm not requesting all of boost/C++0x, but at least _mention_ value semantics.  RAII is bonus points.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, when you use the keyword "new" you actually get back a pointer to an object. This is the only way to instantiate an object type in Java. So when you say you have an "Array of objects" in Java, it's more correct to say that you have an array of pointers to objects.

C++ does not hide the fact that objects are pointers. You can have a variable referencing an object, or you can have a variable referencing a pointer to an object.

In your example, you need to explicitly declare it an as an array of pointers to objects.

```
Players **players = new (Player*)[1];                         // Create an array of player pointers
players[0] = new Player(playerWidth, playerHeight, 20, 1);    // Create a single player
```

And while C++ allows you to explicitly create objects using the keyword ***new***, you must be sure to cleanup your objects once you are done, otherwise they will never be deallocated (known as a memory leak).

This is one of the major differences between C++ and Java; Java's objects are garbage collected and the programmer doesn't have to worry about managing the lifetime of an object.

Once you are done, you will need to cleanup both the individual player that you allocated, as well as the array. Good rule of thumb is that every call to ***new*** should correspond to a call to ***delete***.

```
delete players[0];  // delete the player pointed to by players[0]
delete[] players;   // syntax for deleting arrays
```

However, something interesting to note is that unlike Java, where objects are allocated on the heap, you can create objects on the stack in C++ as if they were primitive types (like int, float, char). This allows you to have objects that are locally scoped, as well as contiguously aligned in memory. There is no way to do this in Java.

If you allocate an array of objects this way, then the default constructor is called for each object in the array.

```
Player p;                           // This calls the default constructor and returns a Player object

Players *players = new Player[5];   // Create an array of player objects
players[0].playerWidth = 8;         // valid because the object has already been constructed

delete[] players; // don't forget to cleanup the array.
                  // no need to cleanup individual player objects, as they are locally scoped.
```

**EDIT:** As some others have mentioned, using a std::vector instead of an array is probably easier in your case (no need to worry about memory allocation) and is on the same order of performance as an array; however I think it is extremely important to become comfortable with the notion of pointers in C++ as they help you understand how memory is organized.

Here is the syntax for creating a vector of Player pointers.

```
std::vector<Player*> players(1); // Creates a vector of pointer to player with length 1
players[0] = new Player(playerWidth, playerHeight, 20, 1); // Create a new player object
delete players[0];                                         // delete the player
```

And the syntax for creating a vector of actual Player object instances (this one is the most preferred solution):

```
std::vector<Player> players(5); // Creates a vector of five player objects
players[0].playerWidth = 8; //already constructed, so we can edit immediately
//no cleanup required for the vector _or_ the players.
```

Comment: "All ... objects are actually pointers to objects" sounds like infinite recursion ;-) Also, no mention of other (better!) ways to allocate?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you do `Foo f = new Foo();`, giving you a dynamically allocated object who's lifetime is managed by the garbage collector.

Now, in C++, `Foo* f = new Foo;` looks similar and also gives you a dynamically allocated object (which you can access via the pointer `f`), but C++ doesn't have a built-in garbage collector. In most cases, the functional C++ equivalent is `Foo f;`, which gives you a local object that is destroyed when you leave the current function (via return or throw).

If you need dynamic allocation, use "smart pointers", which are actually classes that behave like pointers. In C++ 98, there is only `std::auto_ptr` and people often use `boost::shared_ptr` to complement it. In the newer C++ 11, there are `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` that achieve the same.

I hope this gives you some pointers in directions where you need to read a bit, but overall Juanchopanza gave a good advise: Don't use `new` unless you really need to. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have allocated some memory to store an array of one Player (not really useful but it's a first step).

Your variable "players" is now storing the address of the first (and only) slot in this array.
Then by accessing the first Player with players[0], you are able to directly write/read in its memory and no more allocation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose this as a resolution to the problem of setting value of index 0:

```
Player* players = new Player[1];
players[0] = *(new Player(playerWidth, playerHeight, 20, 1));
```

Comment: My c++ is old.
As I understand this your first line create an array of one Player in the stack.
Then in the second line, the new  creates a Player in the heap and copies it to the player in the array.
So it works yes but the copy is expensive and can be what you want or not.

An alternatives would be to create an array of pointer in the first line.