# How to call a function of an object in a list?

Tags: c++, list, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm working on a paint program. The program will store the elements drawn on the graphics window in the sequence they are drawn. I want to use "LIST" to store the shapes drawn. Shapes are of different types i.e. allShapes is the parent class and line is a child class. Please tell me how to store a line inside allShapes list and call its function.

Here's the sample code:

```
    class allShapes
    {
     protected:
     int * points; //vertices of the shape
     int color; //color of the shape
     int n; //no. of points
        public:
    //virtual void draw()= 0;
    virtual void draw()
    {

    }
};
       class line:public allShapes
       {
         public:
     line()
     {
    points = new int[4];
    n = 2;
     }
    void draw()
   {
        //Code here
       }
      };


    int main()
   {

int mouse_x, mouse_y;
char key_pressed;
GP142_open();           /* Open and initialize the GP142 Graphics Window    */
list<allShapes> shapes;
int quit = 0;
while (!quit) {

    switch (GP142_await_event(&mouse_x, &mouse_y, &key_pressed)) {

    case GP142_MOUSE:
        if ((mouse_x > -490 && mouse_x<-445) && (mouse_y>305 && mouse_y < 360)) // If user selects the draw line option
        {
            line newLine;
            shapes.push_back(newLine);
            allShapes check = shapes.front();
            check.draw();
        }
        break;
    case GP142_QUIT:
        quit = 1;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
   }
```

But the program does not call the draw function of line object. I have virtual function draw in allShapes too. How can I call check.draw() to draw a line on the screen?

Comment: You seem to have slicing.

Comment: Could you suggest how to call a derived class function in the above case?

Comment: You could narrow your example down to `list<allShapes> shapes;` and everything from `line newLine;` to `check.draw();`. The rest appears to be noise.

Comment: If my assumption that `line` derives from `allshapes` is correct, you either need a container of pointers or similar (*cough* smart pointers), or need to change the design so that clients don't need to worry about that, like in [this talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil).

Comment: I have add the class code, can you explain it now?

Comment: Make it simple and concise. What you're asking is pretty scattered.

Comment: allShapes is the base class, line is the derived class. I want to know how to store a line inside allShapes list. Plus I want to call a function of line "line.draw()" inside the list.. But it doesn't call line.draw(). How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
        line newLine;
        shapes.push_back(newLine);
        allShapes check = shapes.front();
        check.draw();
```

you are **copying** the line object, instead of **referencing** it.
The container `shapes` should not consist of objects, but of **pointers** to objects.
If you copy a line object into a `allShapes` object, the `allShapes` object will not turn into a `line`.

Declare the container as

```
list<allShapes*> shapes;
```

and then write

```
        line* newLine = new line();
        shapes.push_back(newLine);
        allShapes* check = shapes.front();
        check->draw();
```

and remember to `delete` the objects somewhere.

Comment: @user3566211 You need to understand how to properly handle dynamic allocations if you use this. This is not an easy thing to get right and exception-safe, so you'll probably want to read up on better ways such as R.A.I.I.

Answer (score 1):

With polymorphic objects you cannot reserve just enough storage for the base class and then expect to be able to jam any derived class into that space. That's what you're doing when you say:

```
list<allShapes> shapes;
```

Any time you try to jam a `line` into the space for an `allShapes` object, what will happen is that the `allShapes` part of the `line` will get stored, and the `line` part will be ignored. So then you've got an object that is not a `line`, and calling `.draw()` on it will not call the `line::draw()`. It will call the correct `draw()` method given the dynamic type of the object, which is `allShapes`.

And the same thing happens again when you say:

```
allShapes check = shapes.front();
check.draw();
```

Whatever type results from `shapes.front()` is converted into `allShapes`. If you had a list of `line`s then it would be converted to `allShapes` here.

Using polymorphism generally requires using pointers or references:

```
list<unique_ptr<allShapes>> shapes;
```

Now you can put lines into this collection:

```
shapes.push_back(make_unique<line>()); // make_unique is C++14
```

This way the `line` does not get converted into an `allShapes`, and so when virtual dispatch is done to find the correct method based on the object's real dynamic type, the `draw()` method for `line` will be used.

In order to access an object in the list you can use a reference:

```
allShapes &check = shapes.front();
check->draw();
```

---

If you're coming to C++ from a language that uses reference types by default, such as Java or C#, then you really need to understand how C++ value types work. In those other languages you use pointers all over the place but the syntax doesn't make that obvious. To use pointers in C++ you have to explicitly use special pointer syntax.

You might find another answer where I cover this useful: [Confused with object arrays in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345031/confused-with-object-arrays-in-c/14346668#14346668)

Comment: I have tried your code, the compiler says "unique_ptr" is not a template.

Comment: @user3566211 [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is part of C++11. I don't know what compiler you're using, so I'm simply writing for the most recent version of C++, because that's the easiest to write.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

Comment: @user3566211 then your compiler definitely supports it. You have to include the proper header though: `#include <memory>`